# TensorFlow Model's trainable attribute behavior with nested layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I've encountered a peculiar behavior with TensorFlow when trying to unfreeze specific layers within a nested model. I realized that the trainable attribute of a parent layer/model seems to take precedence over its children layers.

Here's a comparison between two code snippets:

- This one does not actually unfreeze the desired layers:

```
# Assume 'conv_base' is the pre-trained model 
for layer in conv_base.layers:
    if layer.name in layers_to_unfreeze_list:
        layer.trainable = True
```

- This one does unfreeze the desired layers:

```
conv_base.trainable = True
# Now, freeze the layers not in the list
for layer in conv_base.layers:
    if layer.name not in layers_to_unfreeze_list:
        layer.trainable = False
```

In the first snippet, even though I explicitly set certain layers to be trainable, they don't actually become trainable unless the entire parent model (conv_base) is set to trainable, as shown in the second snippet.

Can anyone explain why TensorFlow has this behavior? Any related issues on github?